# Why solutions like pusher claim to be "Real time"?

Tags: webrtc, real-time, pusher

I have been using Pusher for some time now. I always assumed "Real time" meant "instantaneous". Lately I have step into this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing, and a sentence grab my attention:

> "Real-time programs must guarantee response within specified time
>   constraints"

They give an example based on audio processing:

> "Consider an audio DSP example; if a process requires 2.01 seconds to
>   analyze, synthesize, or process 2.00 seconds of sound, it is not
>   real-time. However, if it takes 1.99 seconds, it is or can be made
>   into a real-time DSP process."

My questions:
1. This definition only applies to hardware/electronic devices or can be applied to software too?
2. If applies to software, does it apply to remote services like Pusher?
3. What is the time constraint for pusher to be considered "Real time"?
4. What is the time constraint for other services like WebRTC, Firebase?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the lengthly post that doesn't specifically answer your question, but I hope it will make you better undestand where the "real time" definition comes from.

---

Yes, it is an understandable confusion that "real time" means "instantaneous". But if you really start to think about it you will soon find out that "instantaneous" is difficult to define.

What does instantaneous mean? 0 (zero) seconds response time (as in 0 sec 0 ms 0 ns 0 ps) from the time of the command to the time of the response is physically impossible. We can then try to say that instantaneous would mean that the command-response time is perceived instantaneously, i.e. it would not be seen as a delay. But then... what exactly does "perceived instantaneously" mean? Perceived by humans? Ok, that is good, we are getting somewhere. Human eye and the brain image processing are a very very complex machine and it does not really simply work in fps, but we can use data to approximate some. A human eye can "perceive an image flashed on the screen for 1/250th of a second". That would be  `0.004` seconds or 250 fps. So by this approximation a graphical program would be real time if it has a response time < 0.004 sec or would run faster than @250 fps. But we know that in practice games are perceived smooth by most people at just 60 fps, or `0.01666` seconds. So now we have two different answers. Can we somehow justify them both? Yes. We can say in theory realtime would mean 0.004 seconds, but in practice 0.01666 seconds is enough.

We could be happy and stop here, but we are on a journey of discovery. So lets think further. Would you want a "real time" avionic automation system to have `0.01666` seconds response time? Would you deem acceptable a `0.01666` seconds response time for a "real time" nuclear plant system? Would an oil control system where a valve takes physically 15 seconds to close be defined as "real time" if the command-completion time is `0.0166` seconds? The answer to all these questions is most definitely no. Why? Answer that and you answer why "real time" is defined as it is: "Real-time programs must guarantee response within specified time constraints".

I am sorry, I am not familiar at all with "Pusher", but I can answer your first question and part of your second one: "real times" can be applied to any system that needs to "react" or respond to some form of input. Here "system" is more generic than you might think. A brain would qualify, but in the context of engineering means the whole stack: hardware + software.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. This definition only applies to hardware/electronic devices or can be applied to software too?

It applies to software too. Anything that has hard time constraints. There are real-time operating systems, for example, and even a real-time specification for Java.

> 2. If applies to software, does it apply to remote services like Pusher?

Hard to see how, if a network is involved. More probably they just mean 'timely', or maybe it's just a sloppy way of saying 'push model', as the name implies. Large numbers of users on this site seem to think that 'real-time' means 'real-world'. In IT it means a system that is capable of meeting hard real-time constraints. The Wikipedia definition you cited is correct but the example isn't very satisfactory.

> 3. What is the time constraint for pusher to be considered "Real time"?

The question is malformed. The real question is whether Pusher can actually meet hard real-time constraints at all, and only then what their minimum value might be. It doesn't seem at all likely without operating system and network support.

> 4. What is the time constraint for other services like WebRTC, Firebase?

Ditto.

Comment: Great answer. A small thought: (not familiar with pusher at all, but) a network application can be "real time" without OS/network support. A timeout response can be considered an acceptable response for some systems.

Comment: @bolov I guess so, but then non-realtime operating systems can't even guarantee a timeout period without adding some latency.

Answer (score 1):

Most interpretations of the term "real-time " refer to the traditional static type, often referred to as "hard real-time." Although there is not much of a consensus on the meanings of the terms "hard real-time" and "soft real-time,"  I  provide definitions, based on scientific first principles, of these and other essential terms in [Introduction to Fundamental Principles of Dynamic Real-Time Systems.](https://www.researchgate.net/project/A-Preview-of-Introduction-to-Fundamental-Principles-of-Dynamic-Real-Time-Systems)